# How to Calculate Number of days between two calender dates which are in text format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I'm having a form which is having two input fields with date picker(with the help of jquery ui).One asking a check in date & the other asking check out date.I want to calculate the Number of Days Between those two dates.I am a beginner to javascript.So can any one help me?

Comment: [Properly Calculating Time Differences in JavaScript](http://blog.synyx.de/2012/11/properly-calculating-time-differences-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Use unix timestamp. It's universal tool when you working with time:

```
var a = new Date(2012,11,10);
var b = new Date(2012,11,12);
var dt = (b.getTime() - a.getTime())/(24*3600*1000) //2
```

Comment: first i want convert text format(because i'm using date picker) into date format before calculations

Comment: I think should be the possibility to get Date directly from picker, but if not, you need to parse your date string. Can you show your date format ?

Comment: Date Format is = DD/MM/YYYY (11/01/2012)

Comment: You can split or use RegExp. See second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must first get the value of such input fields, eg:

```
var v1 = document.getElementById('input1Id').value;
var v2 = document.getElementById('input2Id').value;
```

then you have to instantiate two new Javascript Date objects:

```
var parts1 = v1.split('/'); 
var parts2 = v2.split('/');
// this will split your string into date parts, eg. 11/30/2012 would result as an array ['11','30','2012'];

var date1 = new Date(parts1[2],parts1[0],parts1[1]);
var date2 = new Date(parts2[2],parts2[0],parts2[1]);
// remember to check the index of array items considering your date format
```

finally, you just have to subtract one date from the other to get the difference in days:

```
var difference = Math.Abs(date1 - date2);
difference = parseInt(difference / 86400000);
//86400000 are the milliseconds in one day. Parsing to int will round the day - eg.5,4 days results as 5 day
```

---

Edit: Sure, you can reference your html element by his id attribute

```
<input type="text" id="myTextbox">

---

var txb = document.getElementById('myTextbox');
// do anything else to your txb here, if u like
txb.value = difference;
```

that's it!

Comment: Can u tell me how to display the difference(NO of Days) in a TextBox?

Comment: MR.Sandy Mark , Can u tell me how to display the difference in a input Box(read only)?

Comment: The process is correct. Maybe your JS code breaks somewhere before the "txb.value" assignment. Have you tried using a tool like Firebug for Firefox, or Google Chrome development console (press F12) to check for errors?